# Graficas con chart de Laravel y la API de woocomerce

Tags: php, laravel, json, laravel-5

Buenas me estoy trayendo datos de una API de woocomerce y quiero generar graficas con los pedidos.

Normalmente lo realizo de este modo cuando tengo base de datos de compras.

```
$year = date('Y');
        $chart = new Ventachart;
        $chart->labels(['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']);

        for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month ++){
        $totales[] = Order::select(\DB::raw('SUM(total) as total'))
                    ->whereYear('created_at', $year)
                    ->where('estado', 1)
                    ->groupBy(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
                    ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $month)
                    ->pluck('total');
        }
  
        $chart->dataset("Pedidos: $year", 'bar', $totales)->options([
                    'fill' => 'true',
                    'borderColor' => '#3d3d3d',
                    'backgroundColor' => 'rgba(111, 216, 205, 0.54)',
                    'borderWidth' => 1,
                ]);
```

Bien pero al traer datos de los pedidos por API, no tengo una base de datos de la que consultar. si hago un `dd` para saber que me datos me trae del pedido con la API de woocomerce me sale esto:

```
  +"id": 485
  +"parent_id": 0
  +"number": "485"
  +"order_key": "wc_order_3Bp50vmh5va7v"
  +"created_via": "checkout"
  +"version": "4.2.0"
  +"status": "completed"
  +"currency": "EUR"
  +"date_created": "2020-07-21T00:20:46"
  +"date_created_gmt": "2020-07-21T00:20:46"
  +"date_modified": "2020-07-21T09:22:30"
  +"date_modified_gmt": "2020-07-21T09:22:30"
  +"discount_total": "0.00"
  +"discount_tax": "0.00"
  +"shipping_total": "3.93"
  +"shipping_tax": "0.82"
  +"cart_tax": "2.25"
  +"total": "17.74"
  +"total_tax": "3.07"
  +"prices_include_tax": true
  +"customer_id": 12
```

Trae los totales y la fecha, pero no se como montarlo para agruparlo por meses y sus totales. Los datos vienen en Json, no se si eso puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede usar usort para ordenar por fecha:

```php
<?php



$array[0] = array('date_modified' => '2020-07-21T00:20:46', 'date_created' => '2020-08-21T00:20:46');
$array[1] = array('date_modified' => '2020-05-21T00:20:46', 'date_created' => '2020-01-21T00:20:46');
$array[2] = array('date_modified' => '2020-10-21T00:20:46', 'date_created' => '2020-05-21T00:20:46');

function sort_por_clave($clave) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($clave) {
        return (strtotime($a[$clave])> strtotime($b[$clave]));
    };
}

usort($array, sort_por_clave('date_created'));

foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item['date_modified'] . ', ' . $item['date_created'] . "\n";
}



?>
```

[image: Como se puede ver, se ordenaron los items por "date_created"]

Notese que en el sort por clave estoy comparando fechas, asi que no entregará resultados correctos si se usa otro tipo de dato.

Si tiene mas dudas, revise la documentación de php.

Documentación:
[usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php)

Comment: Hola y bienvenida @Daniela C. Montenegro , no lo entiendo, puedo hacer el ejemplo con mis datos?

Comment: @Miguel intente con el ejemplo que acabo de añadir, puede también revisar la documentación de usort, este ordena de la fecha mas antigua a la mas reciente, usando ```strtotime(str)``` para comparar las fechas.